# True getDate() while updating?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, getdate

lets say i have very big table ( many rows)

and i have this sql cmd :

```
update myTable set name='Royi' , dateUpadted=getDate()
```

again , many rows ... - time to update whole table : 3 min. ( already indexed)

my goal is :

each updated row should have its **true** ( *seconds / miliseconds  difference)* `getdate`() !!!

so my desire result :

```
name | dateUpadated
___________________
royi |      12:00:00  -- getDate() here was 12:00:00
...  |         ...
...  |         ...
...  |         ...
royi |      12:01:13  -- getDate() here was 12:01:13
...  |         ...
...  |         ...
...  |         ...
royi |      12:03:01  -- getDate() here was 12:03:01
```

how can I do it ?

*( I dont want to us `cursor`)*

is there any switch which says to `getDate()` function :

*" use your current value and not the one which youve started with " ?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap it inside a scalar UDF to get it to be re-evaluated for each row.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GETDATE()
RETURNS DATETIME    
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN GETDATE();
END
```

Comment: INHO udf cant return getDate / dynamic functions.... or is it in 2005 ? i tried once with rand and came into a problem....

Comment: Been able to use `getdate()` in UDFs since 2005+

Comment: @Soren  sais it is its true value already.... i dont think so... what do you say ?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 has allowed some of the non-deterministic functions that were not allowed in 2000. In 2005 you can now use
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
@@MAX_CONNECTIONS
GET_TRANSMISSION_STATUS
@@PACK_RECEIVED
GETDATE
@@PACK_SENT
GETUTCDATE
@@PACKET_ERRORS
@@CONNECTIONS
@@TIMETICKS
@@CPU_BUSY
@@TOTAL_ERRORS
@@DBTS
@@TOTAL_READ
@@IDLE
@@TOTAL_WRITE and
@@IO_BUSY

You still cannot use
NEWID
RAND
NEWSEQUENTIALID and
TEXTPTR

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/23/sql-server-2005-use-of-non-deterministic-function-in-udf-find-day-difference-between-any-date-and-today/

Comment: RE: True value, logically an update is a single unit that happens "all at once" so makes sense they should all have the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* the "true" value, though. The `UPDATE` happens in a transaction; changes are committed in one go rather than per row. If you want rows updated individually, a cursor is exactly what you want.